# Appending to each element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I have a jQuery script shown bellow. It is suppose to get AWS ML prediction and compare the score and depending upon the score append to a cell in a table the correct prediction. All these cells have the same class `prediction`. When the button is clicked and this script is triggered, it does everything correctly but when it gets to the appending part it throwing an error saying `Cannot read property 'append' of undefined`.

When i run the same script inside chrome console it appends correctly to the correct places. I am not really sure why this is happening.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var highPred="";
        $("#predict").click(function(){
        var predictionTables = $(".prediction");
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                var predictedScoresAWS=[];
                var params = {
                  Record: myData[i]
                };
                machinelearning.predict(params, function(err, data) {
                  if (err){
                    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                  } else{
                    console.log(data);           // successful response
                    // data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    predictedScoresAWS.push(data.Prediction.predictedScores['Reduce purge history day count']);
                    predictedScoresAWS.push(data.Prediction.predictedScores['Increase the java heap space']);
                    predictedScoresAWS.push(data.Prediction.predictedScores['Successful run']);
                    predictedScoresAWS.push(data.Prediction.predictedScores['Other error']);
                    console.log(predictedScoresAWS)
                    var highPredIndex = predictedScoresAWS.indexOf(Math.max(...predictedScoresAWS))
                    switch(highPredIndex){
                        case 0:
                            highPred='Reduce purge history day count';
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            highPred='Increase the java heap space';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            highPred='Successful run';
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            highPred='Other error';
                    }
                    console.log(highPred);
                    console.log(predictionTables);
                    console.log(predictionTables[i])
                    while (predictedScoresAWS.length) { predictedScoresAWS.pop(); }
                    predictionTables[i.].append(highPred);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a subscript with a jQuery collection it returns the DOM object, not a jQuery object. You should use `.eq()` to get the jQuery object, and then you can call the jQuery `append()` method.

```
predictionTables[i].append(highPred);
```

should be:

```
predictionTables.eq(i).append(highPred);
```

Another problem is that you're trying to use the iteration variable `i` in an asynchronous callback. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue) for the problem with this and many solutions. If you can use ES6, just change `var i = 0` to `let i = 0`.

Comment: I did try to use that but when i do I don't get any errors but i don't see the string being appended to the table cell. @Barmar

Comment: I just noticed that this is an async callback in a `for` loop. So you're running into this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did find a way around this. Seems that appending doesn't really work like that for some reason. But i did try the answers from other stackoverflow question and was able to get it working. Thank you!